# Custom Theme resets after performing search

Tags: android

I am setting a custom theme in a "Contacts" application the following way...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if ("Red".equalsIgnoreCase( getIntent().getStringExtra( "Theme" )))
    {
        super.setTheme(R.style.red);
    }
    else if ("Green".equalsIgnoreCase( getIntent().getStringExtra( "Theme" )))
    {
        super.setTheme(R.style.green);
    }
    else if ("Blue".equalsIgnoreCase( getIntent().getStringExtra( "Theme" )))
    {
        super.setTheme(R.style.blue);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mainDBHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    /*
     * added for the search functionality
     */
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        name = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    }
```

This works great, but after using the search functionality the theme is changed back to the default.  I have a separate activity where you can select your theme.  That activity starts a new mainActivity intent with the String(putExtra): Red, Green, or Blue.  Can someone tell me what changes I need to make to prevent this?